# How to understand which constraints are not working in an inline code assembly?

Tags: c++, gcc, x86, sse, inline-assembly

When I run the assembly code bellow it gets me the `error: impossible constraint in ‘asm’`.

```
int main(){
    int constant[4] = {0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff};
    int source_image[8] = {10,56,54,88,61,250,80,157};
    int negative_image[8];
    int len = 8;
    asm(
        "movdqa xmm7, %[constant]"
        "mov %esi, %[source_image]"
        "mov %edi, %[negative_image]"
        "mov %ecx, %[len]"
        
        "movdqa %xmm0, [esi]"
        "movdqa %xmm1, [esi+16]"
        "movdqa %xmm2, [esi+32]"
        "movdqa %xmm3, [esi+48]"
        "PSUBS  %xmm0, %xmm7"
        "PSUBS  %xmm1, %xmm7"
        "PSUBS  %xmm2, %xmm7"
        "PSUBS  %xmm3, %xmm7"
        "movdqa [edi], %xmm0"
        "movdqa [edi+16], %xmm1"
        "movdqa [edi+32], %xmm2"
        "movdqa [edi+48], %xmm3"
        "add %esi, $64"
        "add %edi, $64"
        : [negative_image] "=x" (negative_image)
        : [len] "r" (len), [constant] "r" (constant), [source_image] "r" (source_image)
    );
    return 0;
}
```

how can I understand which constraint are not OK?
And also another question is that how to use labels in assembly?

Comment: Suggestion only: this would be much easier, more robust, more portable and more efficient if you just used the standard intrinsics instead of trying to outdo the compiler with hand-written assembler.

Comment: @PaulR thanks Paul,  but actually it's part of my homework. I can't use intrinsics.

Comment: It's the `"=x" (negative_image)` of course, the rest are harmless register constraints. In general, you just have to stare at them long enough until you find the error or do a binary search removing stuff. Note your code is wrong for many reasons, but you did not ask that. (E.g. wrong operand order, missing `%` signs, missing clobbers, using aligned instructions, not using specific register constraints,...)

Comment: @Jester thanks Jester, could you please tell me which part of my code is wrong exactly, tell me in the answer box please and also tell me how to correct them please.

Comment: naturally you are looking at a disassembly of the compiler output to see how the compiler dealt with your code?  and then as a result you have specific questions as to here is my expectation, here is the result, what went wrong?

Comment: @old_timer: This is a compile-time error, so the compiler refuses to generate any assembly output.  (And even if it did, these aren't all valid instructions, e.g. there's no `psubs`, and the adds have an immediate *destination*.  So fixing the constraints could let you get assembly output from `gcc -S`, but not a binary you could *dis*assemble, because `as` would reject this.)

Comment: This question is asking how to know *which* constraint or combination of them is leading to `error: impossible constraint in ‘asm’.`, since it doesn't tell you which one it didn't like.  That's actually a reasonable question, despite the asm template itself being full of other errors which distract from the question being asked.